# gSOAP deletes referenced values in objects after request finished

Tags: c++, web-services, qt, pointers, gsoap

i'm using gSOAP to request information from a SOAP webservice

the soap webservice returns an object.
i do the request in a calls called: "dataconnector"

in dataconnector i can output all values for the returned object
but outside that all the referenced values in the object are null.

i did some searching and apperantly gSOAP deletes everything unless you remove in from the deallocation chain with soap_unlink()

i tried but it didn't help
this is my code

any ideas of what i'm doing wrong?

```
QList<ns1__calls*> calls;

datacheckPortBindingProxy service;
ns1__getCalls request;
std::string un("4444");
request.username = &un;
ns1__getCallsResponse response;
if (service.getCalls(&request, &response) == SOAP_OK){
    qDebug() << "succesfull response";
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i< response.return_.size(); i++){
    ns1__calls* call = response.return_.at(i);

    qDebug() << QString(call->roomId->c_str());
    qDebug() << "      with type_id: " << (call->typeId-1) ;

    calls.append(call);
    soap_unlink(request.soap, call);
}
```

**EDIT**

nvm
apperantly you need to unlink all the seperate values of the object

like this:

```
soap_unlink(response.soap, call->roomId);
soap_unlink(response.soap, call->display);
soap_unlink(response.soap, call->location);
soap_unlink(response.soap, call->staffAidId);
soap_unlink(response.soap, call->firstName);
soap_unlink(response.soap, call->lastName);
```

isn't there an eazier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a specific gSOAP or web-services question. When the variable `response` gets out of scope, it deallocates the memory it has used and in my opinion you should really not *unlink* the memory gSOAP has reserved. If you unlink it, you are responsible for freeing it!

The way to go is to make a copy of the objects referenced by the `ns1__calls` pointers.

```
QList<ns1__calls> calls; // QList of instances instead of pointers
...
calls.append(*call); // append a copy
// soap_unlink(request.soap,call); // not needed!
```